# How to scrape in csv from 2 templates with the same parent node?(python, web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I extract information in csv from 2 templates with the same parent node? For the first template it gives ok but for the second it gives wrong information in csv(I attached the csv and the code). This is a web scraping program and I made this program with python. I will appreciate any help.

THIS IS THE OUTPUT(CSV)

[image]

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import io

# set the proxies to hide actual IP

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://5.189.133.231:80',
    'https': 'https://27.111.43.178:8080'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'Product price', 'ASIN', 'Product Weight', 'Product dimensions', 'URL']

with open('csv/sort_products.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)

links = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Multi-Use-Programmable-Packaging/dp/B00FLYWNYQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520264922&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggh',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Amagle-Flexible-Batteries-Operated-Included/dp/B01NGTKTDK/ref=sr_1_2?s=furniture&ie=UTF8&qid=1520353343&sr=1-2&keywords=-jhgf'
]

for i in range(len(links)):

    driver.get(links[i])
    asinFound = False
    product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"][1]')
    prod_title = [x.text for x in product_title]

    try:
        prod_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]').text
    except:
        prod_price = 'No price'


    if asinFound == False:  # try template one
        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[5]/td').text
            asinFound=True
        except:
            print('no ASIN template one')

        try:
            weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td').text
        except:
            print('no weight template one')

        try:
            dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
        except:
            print('no dimension template one')

    if asinFound == False:  # try template two
        try:
           asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
           asinFound=True
        except:
            print('no ASIN template two')

        try:
            weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td').text
        except:
            print('no weight template two')

        try:
           dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id ="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]/tbody/tr[3]/td').text
        except:
            print('no dimension template two')

    try:
        data = [prod_title[0], prod_price, asin, weight, dimension, links[i]]
    except:
        print('no data')

    with io.open('csv/sort_products.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this to get the information you would like to grab. I used `selenium` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` (not necessary though). The main problem was that the `Product information` in the first url is within `id` name `productDetails_detailBullets_sections1` whereas the `Product information` in the second url is within id name `productDetails_techSpec_section_1`. I had to write selectors in such a way so that the script can get information from the two links.

This is the modified code:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Multi-Use-Programmable-Packaging/dp/B00FLYWNYQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520264922&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggh',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Amagle-Flexible-Batteries-Operated-Included/dp/B01NGTKTDK/ref=sr_1_2?s=furniture&ie=UTF8&qid=1520353343&sr=1-2&keywords=-jhgf'
]

def get_information(driver,urls):
    with open("productDetails.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(['Title','Dimension','Weight','ASIN'])

        for url in urls:
            driver.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
            title = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
            dimension = ([item.select_one("td").get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("#prodDetails [id^='productDetails_'] tr") if "Product Dimensions" in item.text]+["N\A"])[0]
            weight = ([item.select_one("td").get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("#prodDetails [id^='productDetails_'] tr") if "Item Weight" in item.text]+["N\A"])[0]
            ASIN = ([item.select_one("td").get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("#prodDetails [id^='productDetails_'] tr") if "ASIN" in item.text]+["N\A"])[0]

            writer.writerow([title,dimension,weight,ASIN])
            print(f'{title}\n{dimension}\n{weight}\n{ASIN}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        get_information(driver,links)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

I skipped the proxy part. However, you can include them as required.

Comment: Yes! I think I will migrate to beautifulsoup. Do you know if I can use beautifulsoup for all amazon templates?(I think there are 19 different templates)(optional)

Comment: Usually it works in most of the cases (using the combo). I never worked with amazon so I'm not so sure it won't dissapoint you. However, you can always get back to pure selenium if anything undesirable comes along.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!